# Is it possible to sign Git commits when using SVN?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, pgp

I am using `git-svn` to push to a remote SVN server as well as remote Git repositories.

I would like to sign my Git commits using PGP, but I cannot do this before a `git-svn dcommit`, as this will modify the commit message. I can `--amend` a signature to the commit after `dcommit`, but the commit message containing the signature will be reverted the next time I communicate with the SVN server.

I recognize that SVN has no way to PGP sign commits; I only would like to have the signatures in my Git repo.

Is there any way this is possible?

Comment: No clue about git-svn, but you could always make signed tags and keep them local

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot do this before a git-svn dcommit, as this will modify the commit message

That would be problematic, indeed, for existing commits.
But that would not prevent you to:

- keep the Git-SVN commit history as is
- create *new* (signed) commits in Git that you should be able to `git-svn dcommit` without issue.